# PThreads Address Space

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Is there any way to force threads to have independent address spaces? I'd like to have many threads running loops using local variables - but it seems they all share the same variables.

for example

```
for (i = args->start; i < args->end; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        if (quickFind(getReverse(array[i]), 0, size - 1)) {
            printf("%s\n", array[i]);
            //strcpy(array[i], "");
        }
    }
```

`i` seems to be shared across threads.

Comment: don't use global or static variables and don't pass pointers between threads and you shouldn't have too much trouble. Only thing to be mindful of are library functions that DO use globals or static varaibles.....

Comment: Also, your example isn't really showing where it is the memory is being shared, where are those variables declared?

Comment: you mean like `fork()`? ...you can still use shared memory, semaphors,...

Comment: Where and how is `i` declared?

Comment: What do you mean by "independent address spaces"? Each thread gets its own stack, which should be more than enough in this case. If you declare `i` as a local, function-scoped variable, then it will be placed inside the thread's stack and not shared with anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Threads share the memory space of their parent process. Its their characteristic. If you don't want that to happen you can create a new process, which'll have it's own address space, using fork().

If you do decide to use fork() remember that, on successfully creating a child process, it returns 0 to the child process and the PID of the child process to the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Yes it's possible for each thread to have its own copy of the variable `i`.

**Long answer**:

All threads share the same address space and the OS does not provide any protection to prevent one thread from accessing memory used by another.  However, the memory can be partitioned so that it will only be accessed by a single thread rather than being shared by all threads.

By default each thread receives its own stack.  So if you allocate a variable on the stack then it will typically only be accessed by a single thread.  Note that it is possible to pass a pointer to a stack variable from one thread to another, but this is not recommended and could be the source of the sort of problems that you are seeing.

Another way for a thread to receive its own copy of a variable is using thread local storage.  This allows each thread to have its own copy of a global variable.

In summary, although threads share an address space they can work on private data.  But you need to be careful with how you are sharing data between threads and avoid data races.

Answer (score 0):

Just have each thread call into the function separately. Each invocation of a function gets its own instances of all local variables. If this wasn't true, recursion wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be really lazy, and make no design changes whatsoever (not really recommended), you can modify the declaration of `i` to something like `__thread int i`, so that every thread will have its own instance of that variable.

If you were using OpenMP instead of Posix threads, you could also say `#pragma omp threadprivate(i)` before the first usage of `i`.